# Spring 4 + aspects

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I have problem with aspects. They don't firing. I have small aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class SynchronizingAspect {
    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    @Around("synchronize() && @annotation(Synchronized)")
    public void synchronize(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.SEVERE, "LOOOOOOOOL");
        joinPoint.proceed();        

    }
}
```

and a method with annotation:

```
@Synchronized
@Transactional
@Override
public User create(Map<String, Object> values) {
    return super.create(values); 
}
```

in my config file I have

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

I'm using spring 4.1.5

and dependencies for aop:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

I will be very grateful if someone could tell me why it doesn't working and help me with fix it.

Best regards, 
Matt.

Comment: I changed the aspect dependencies to 1.8.5 version but it doesn't change anythink.

Comment: Have you tried splitting `@Pointcut` and `@Around` in your aspect into two separate methods?

Comment: Yes I tired somethink like this http://imgur.com/cqLWuQ0

Comment: Where are you calling your `create` method from?  From another Spring bean?

Comment: Yes, from controller - http://imgur.com/xOJeJR7

Comment: Is your aspect in a package that is covered by `@ComponentScan` or `<context:component-scan>`?

Comment: Yes. Aspect is in pl.flomedia.springtpl.aspect and this is My @ComponentScan - http://imgur.com/wBlt1Tm

Comment: I retract the previous comment, you do need `@Component` for `@Aspect` to be picked up.

Comment: Have you got any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it. I remove the `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` and use `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` and now this is working. Thanks for responses!

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `@Transactional` on `create` method is interfering with your custom Aspect.

Try specifying [`@Order`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html) on your aspect as below. This will make the aspect with execution order higher to that of `@Transactional`. (*Note that argument value 1 is arbitrary to override the default [lowest precedence](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html#value--) set for order*)

```
@Aspect
@Component
@Order(1)
public class SynchronizingAspect { ... }
```